# My ASP connection dies when sending large response

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I am making a function that changes the text in a textarea and the connection to the server dies when a large value is set.

Here is the code:

```
    public void OpenFileASP(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string TextFromFile = FileManager1.SelectedItems[0].PhysicalPath;
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(TextFromFile);
            MainTextBox.Value = "";

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                MainTextBox.Value += "\n" + line;
            }
       }
    }
```

There is no problem with files smaller than around 1kb.

Any idea what could be wrong/is there a better method to do this?

Thx

Comment: How you call that ? maybe you have a throw error that you do not handle, and the connection simple close.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your web.config.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" />
</system.web>
```